# How to input different types of parameter to one function in Python?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I wanted to make my own specified module in Python for scientific work and a crucial step is to design my function. For example, I would like to build a Freundlich adsorption isotherm function: output = K*(c^n), with K and n as constants, c is the concentration of a compound (variable).

```
def Freundlich(K, c, n):
    ads_Freundlich = K * c ** n
    return ads_Freundlich
```

However, with these codes I could only input K, c, n all as single figures. I would like to know how can I run a function by giving the constant(s) as figures and the variable(s) as lists (or pandas series, etc.). In the end, I want the function to return a list. Thanks!

Comment: this should just work with `numpy`. With lists, you have to do the looping yourself, they do not implement vectorized operations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nice advice, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *vanilla* Python you have to use something like this:

```
def Freundlich(K, c, n_list):
    return [K * c ** n for n in n_list]
```

If you pass a list to the function you wrote, it will **not** be automatically vectorized as you seem to expect; it will throw an error instead. However, as [@juanpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) says, such an automatic conversion is performed by a python module called `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you, this did work. But for functions which contain '+' operators, an error comes out: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' `. I did the calculation with another function `return [(K*Smax*c)/(1 + K*c)) for c in c_list]`.

Comment: @Michael If that is the case, the problem on your code is not on the `return [(K*Smax*c)/(1 + K*c)) for c in c_list]` line. It is further up.. You are at some point adding an integer to a list. something like `c_list = 5 + c_list` or so

Comment: I am sorry that my expression in the question text is not clear enough and misleading. The 'n' is not a list, the 'c' is the only list instead. I understood your answer so I didn´t mention that you have mistaken them two.